# What is the procedure to upgrade a Nintendo 3DS SD Card to a larger one using a PC?

Tags: sd-card, gaming, micro-sd-card

I am preparing to upgrade my SD card on my Nintendo 3DS XL.  It's currently a 4 GB card. I want to move it to an SD card with Nintendo's maximum limit of 32 GB. (I have heard this limit is able to be worked around, maybe best for another question?) I will be moving my data to a Micro SD card for future compatibility with the NEW Nintendo 3DS.

What is the best way to do this? I have a Windows 7 laptop with a SD card slot. I may need help formatting the memory card for the Nintendo 3DS system too.

Ideal answers will include what programs are required for all major operating systems (OS X, Windows, Linux). It should also account for the major revisions of the Nintendo 3DS lines (Nintendo 3DS, Nintendo 3DS XL, New Nintendo 3DS XL).

Comment: Nintendo seems to recommend the utility here to format an SD Card for the system.  It has a Windows and Mac version https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/

Comment: eh. Lots of places do. Its the official sd card formatter after al, and would format it to FAT32 - is that the correct file system type?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. I've also heard it's possible to format an SDXC (64GB and up) memory card for use in the 3DS, despite Nintendo's claims otherwise. It doesn't appear to be possible with the tool above though.

Comment: If so, it's likely the only reason the 3DS can't use larger capacity cards, is the lack of exFat support.

Comment: Naw, windows dosen't support bigger fat partitions for *formatting*. I suppose they want to play it safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they recommend the 'official' SD card formatter, its almost certainly fat32. There's a few nice things there - there's no file permissions to move over, and its about as simple and as well understood a format as any (and I'm pretty sure mkdosfs on linux does the same)

Just copy out the files from the old sd card, make sure the new sd card is fat32 as well, and copy the files over. If you want to be paranoid, check the md5 sums of the files on either disk. Test to see if your stuff works.

I wouldn't bet my lunch on it,but [there's a 32gb size limit for FAT32](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314463) on window's own formatter. There's [third party options](http://www.ridgecrop.demon.co.uk/fat32format.htm) that support it, (and mkdosfs for linux and maybe osx would probably do it with no fuss). Assuming there's no hard limit on the 3DS (or other issues), it *should* work - just see what setting the official formatter uses for block size I guess. You can format the SD card with whatever tool anyway - the SD card association just has a few handy defaults that makes it simpler, so something like the ridgecrop tool or mkdosfs (or its OS X equivalent should do the trick).

Comment: Ahh, I'm copying my files over to a 32GB card formatted with the official SD Card utility for Windows. I'll report back if it works (it should, I copied my files off the sd card fairly easily a moment ago).

Comment: Official block size for the 4GB card that came with my 3DS appears to be 64. I've set the format utility to do the same.

Comment: Success! After copying the files to my 32GB SD Card, the 3DS booted up with no issues. I'm able to play my downloaded games.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! I'll try doing the same for a 64 GB Micro SD Card in Fat32 format ASAP.

Comment: Manually formatting a 64GB card had great results. The system reports that available blocks are vastly increased over the 32 GB.